# Fastest way to find LCM and HCF of multiple numbers?

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, least-common-multiple

Is there any shortcut approach to find LCM and HCF of multiple numbers apart from prime factorization and hit and trial method (writing down all the multiples of respective numbers and comparing them for finding common multiple)?

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
\operatorname{HCF}(a, b, c) = \operatorname{HCF}(\operatorname{HCF}(a, b), c)
$$
and similarily for LCM. So using an algorithm which is efficient for two numbers (say, the Euclidean algorithm for HCF, or multiplying them and dividing them by the HCF to get the LCM) will be relatively efficient for more than two numbers as well, just applied repeatedly.

---

Example: $a = 6, b = 10$ and $c = 15$. Then their HCF is $1$, and their LCM is $30$ (this is easily confirmed with prime factorisations, for instance). Following my desciption above, we get
$$
\operatorname{HCF}(6, 10, 15) = \operatorname{HCF}(\operatorname{HCF}(6, 10), 15)
$$
so first we find $\operatorname{HCF}(6, 10)$ with the Euclidean algorithm:
$$
\operatorname{HCF}(6, 10) = \operatorname{HCF}(4, 6)\\
= \operatorname{HCF}(2, 4) = \operatorname{HCF}(0, 2) = 2
$$
which then gives
$$
\operatorname{HCF}(\operatorname{HCF}(6, 10), 15) = \operatorname{HCF}(2, 15)\\
= \operatorname{HCF}(1, 2) = 1
$$
As for LCM, we get
$$
\operatorname{LCM}(6, 10, 15) = \operatorname{LCM}(\operatorname{LCM}(6, 10), 15)
$$
so first we find $\operatorname{LCM}(6, 10)$. We know from above that their HCF is $2$, so the LCM is $6\cdot 10\div 2 = 30$. Thus
$$
\operatorname{LCM}(\operatorname{LCM}(6, 10), 15) = \operatorname{LCM}(30, 15)
$$
The Euclidean algorithm gives $\operatorname{HCF}(30, 15) = 15$, so $\operatorname{LCM}(30, 15) = 30\cdot 15\div 15 = 30$.

Comment: Actually, for LCF you can just use the Euclidean algorithm directly on the triple of numbers: For instance, go from $(6, 10, 15)$ to $(6, 10, 5)$ to $(1, 10, 5)$ and once you see the $1$ there you're done. The advantage of this is that you can be clever with which order you do subtractions, and there is no downside because if you don't immediately spot something obvious and simple, you can just take the first two numbers of the tuple, and you're doing exactly what you would be doing with the pairwise algorithm described above.

Comment: I was about to suggest thst! And once you see $6$ with $5$ you know there's no common factor but $1$.

Comment: Such no effort questions (especially with such an obvious solution) shouldn't be answered.

Comment: @AnneBauval I think four year old questions aren't the most fruitful place to put that effort. But sure, I do agree.